# How to remove an XML attribute from a tag generated by an WSO2 ESB application?

Tags: java, xml, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I am pretty new in **WSO2 ESB** and I am finding the following difficulty generating an XML document. It works pretty fine but, after that this document is generated I have to remove an XML attribute on a tag.

I have this sequence code that generates the XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="transferSequence" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <ds:FindTransfer xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                <ds:transferId>$1</ds:transferId>
            </ds:FindTransfer>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:transferId" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:FindTransfer"/>
    <callout endpointKey="pgrfasEndpoint">
        <source xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
        <target xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:s11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xpath="s11:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1] | s12:Body/child::*[fn:position()=1]"/>
    </callout>
    <enrich>
        <source clone="true" xmlns:ds="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="//ds:transfer"/>
        <target type="body"/>
    </enrich>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/xml"/>
    <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="post"/>
    <!-- Store message into message store -->
    <store messageStore="transferMessageStore"/>
</sequence>
```

that generates an XML document like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transfer xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" username="my_user" password="my_pswd">
    <providerpid>00AB40</providerpid>
    <recipientpid>00AD12</recipientpid>
    <symbol>SMTA1234</symbol>
    <type>SMTA</type>
    <materials>
        <doi>10.0155/1463</doi>
        <doi>10.0155/1464</doi>
    </materials>
</transfer>
```

It is correct, the only problem is that the  element have this attribute setted on it **xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"**

I absolutly need to remove this attribute in the simplest way (for example using a **Script** mediator (using JavaScript) or something else.

How can I do it?

Comment: xslt remove namespace

Comment: or you payload mediator again to recreate same message without namespace.

Comment: Look at here http://wso2.com/project/data-services/2.6.3/docs/namespace_handling.html . Worth to try to set empty namespace for dss server <result defaultNamespace="">

Comment: Check the answer from
[How to remove an XML attribute from a tag generated by an WSO2 ESB application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721850/how-to-remove-an-xml-attribute-from-a-tag-generated-by-an-wso2-esb-application)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the payload / XML into a XSLT mediator (and transform the content using a stylesheet)  and remove the namespaces.

The following block works fine to me. checkout..

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
     <xsl:element name="{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Create one local-entries as below (my filename was `removeRootElement.xslt.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="removeRootElement.xslt" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  
 <!-- keep comments -->
 <xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- remove element prefix -->
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <!-- process attributes -->
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <!-- remove attribute prefix -->
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet></localEntry>
```

Then make a proxy service (my filename was `XSLTMediate.xml`) using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="XSLTMediateTest" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <xslt key="removeRootElement.xslt"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Deploy your service and run with URL
`http://{{ip}}:{{port}}/services/XSLTMediate`
and sample body

```
<getBusNo xmlns:p="http://transport.org" cal="10">
<xs:rootId xmlns:xs="http://transport.org">2</xs:rootId>
</getBusNo>
```

The output will be

```
<getBusNo cal="10">
    <rootId>2</rootId>
</getBusNo>
```