# Remove default namespace

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

how i can change or remove default namespace, included by dss service in soap body :

xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
and
xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"

```
<body>
   <p:insert_data xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:param0 xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">?</xs:param0>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:param1 xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">?</xs:param1>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:param2 xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">?</xs:param2>
      <!--Exactly 1 occurrence-->
      <xs:param3 xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">?</xs:param3>
</p:insert_data>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721850/how-to-remove-an-xml-attribute-from-a-tag-generated-by-an-wso2-esb-application

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own namespaces.

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS350/Defining+Namespaces

Comment: i used DSS for upsert operation, and left default naespace blanck. when i execute it, these namespaces have been specified by default. and i dont know haow i can remove it.